# Jquery cookie not executing conditional statement

Tags: jquery

I've set the cookie to.

this is executed on click event.

```
  $("#scan").click(function(){
     $.cookie('scanner', true);
  });
```

Now when it is set I do something like this.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        var test = $.cookie('scanner');
        alert(test);
        if(test == true){

        setTimeout(function(){

            $("#scan").click();

        },10);
        }

});
```

Now when I open my page in new tab alert pops out saying it's true but not executing the click function. Why is that?

Thanks,

**EDIT: ALSO how can i delete the cookie when i closed my tab not the browser?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cookie value is saved and read as a string.

Try with

```
 if (test == "true") {
```

Comment: Also how can i delete it on when i close the tab of my page?

Comment: To delete a cookie, set its value to null : `$.cookie('scanner', null);`. If you want to delete it when the page is closed, you have no reliable cross-browser way, so you'd better delete it at page opening...

Comment: I can't delete it because i need it to retain on new page opening. i just need to delete it on tab close.

Comment: What do you mean "tab close" ? Is this tab a native tab or one of your page ? In the second case, use the code of my previous comment. In the first case, doing it at closing or opening is the same.

Comment: the tab on which my webpage is located. when i close that tab then i again open my page the cookie still remains i need it to be deleted when i close the tab of my webpage. when i close the whole browser cookie is deleted. i just need something like that that when i close the tab of my webpage cookie is deleted. thanks,